# Problems with Prestashop Jquery Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion, prestashop

I am currently working on a Prestashop template wich Categories must be shown as accordion (without products), so I am adding manually the calls from the smarty/php code to the accordion, so automatically will show all the ones created.

I AM USING THE JQUERY ACCORDION (http://jqueryui.com/accordion)

The main problem there is the following:

JS ADDED:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#accordion" )
     .accordion({
        header: "> div > h3"
      })
     .sortable({
        axis: "y",
        handle: "h3",
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
          // IE doesn't register the blur when sorting
          // so trigger focusout handlers to remove .ui-state-focus
          ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

and everything works with this:

```
  <div class="product_list_details">
     <div class="product_list_details_left">
       <div class="grid-container">                
         <ul id="product_list" class="grid">
           <div id="accordion">
             <div class="group">
               <h3>{if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</h3>
               <p class="product_desc">{$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}</p>
               <h3>{if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}{$product.name|truncate:35:'...'|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</h3>
               <p class="product_desc">{$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
         </ul>
       </div>   
     </div>
  </div>
```

But as you can see I have to repeat it twice for make it work, because if I do not, the script does not work. I'll add a screen to show you what do I mean.

EXAMPLE:
[image: SCREEN]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add JS to a .tpl file you should do it either with the `{literal}*script*{/literal}` tag, or with the addJS(path-to-js) method in the module to be displayed hook.